# Can't position objects with GSAP

Tags: javascript, tween, gsap

I'm taking real simple examples from their documentation in one I re-size and re-position a photo.  The re-size part works fine but it won't re-position.
Here's my code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>animate</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #test { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #f72; }
</style>

    <!--CDN link for the latest TweenMax-->
**<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>**
</head>

<body>
    **<div id="test"></div>
    <img id="photo" src="Putin.jpg">**

<script>
    **var photo = document.getElementById("photo"); 
    TweenLite.to(photo, 2.5, {width:100});  // this works
    TweenLite.to(photo, 4, {left:300});   // this does nothing

    var thing = document.getElementById('test');
    TweenLite.to(thing, 1, {left:200});   // this does nothing
    TweenLite.to(thing, 1, {top:100});    // this does nothing**
</script>

</body>
```

you can run it here: http://www.jimslounge.com/gsap_test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

I would always wait until the window has loaded before executing code that relies on a external libraries:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var photo = document.getElementById("photo"); 
    TweenMax.to(photo, 4, {x:300});
}
```

Secondly, you are loading the **TweenMax** library, so you need to use **TweenMax** instead of **TweenLite**

Thirdly, besides not quite being sure if you need to define your block as position absolute when not animating the padding or margin, you should definitely pass the x instead of left attribute

```
TweenMax.to(photo, 4, {x:300});
```

Give it a go and let me know if this helps

See a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hitbox/QbyCU/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Please also see the js fiddle example which works.

Comment: while css didn't help I went back and tried your suggestion about absolute positioning,  works!!